# Losing the synthetic event in useState's function for update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the useState hook for functional components where I am facing a strange behavior.
I am using the useState like this.

```
const [state, setState] = useState({ title: "", amount: '' });
```

Same state I am binding with form data. If I use to like this

```
<input type="text" id="title" value={state.title}
    onChange={event => setState( { ...state, title: event.target.value })} />
```

then it works perfectly, but if I use the previous State for real-time state like this

```
<input type="text" id="title" value={state.title}
    onChange={event => setState((prevState) => {
            return {
              ...prevState,
              title: event.target.value
            }
          })
          } />
```

then **event** get loose on the second keypress. On research, I have found that it is due to event pooling and I can use event.persist() for that.
My question is, why is it works in 1st scenario I explained and why not in 2nd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What actually here is happening is due to **closure** and the way how React handle the event.
function under setState is closure function, so the value of event gets locked on first execution, and closure tries to fetch the first value(locked value). React implements [Event pooling](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling) in which, event object will be nullified after event callback is invoked.

but React also gives the way to pull out the **event** object from event pooling with persist method as below.

```
   `onChange={event => {
  event.persist();
  setState(prevSt....`
```

By this, React will never nullify the object, so closure will always have the access to event method.

Answer (score 0):

Because in the second iteration, Event parameter gets undefined. So it can't find the value it throws null exception. You can simply overcome the situation by passing an arrow function

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState} = React;

const Example = ({title}) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [state, setState] = useState({ title: "", amount: '' });
  const setValue = (value) => {

      setState((prevState) => {
      console.log(prevState);
            return {
              ...prevState,
              title: value//(event.target?event.target.value : 'val')
            }
          })
  }
  return (
    <div>
    <input type="text" id="title" value={state.title}
    onChange={event => setState({ ...state, title: event.target.value })} />
    <input type="text" id="title" value={state.title}
    onChange={event => setValue(event.target.value)} 
           />
          </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example title="Example using Hooks:" />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So in  `setState( { ...state, title: event.target.value })` you are spreading the state which means maintaining the current state and changing  the `title` of the state object to the current value in the `input`. while in

```
setState((prevState) => {
        return {
          ...prevState,
          title: event.target.value
        }
      })
```

event pooling is used so the `prevState` is event data(in this case the state object) which is sent as a callback, so when you enter the first character the event object is in effect being sent back to the pool and by the time you enter the second character the event object will have already been returned to the pool and hence event would be `null`. so to overcome this you can make the event persistent by using the `event.persist()` which would allow you to use the event properties in an asynchronous way, hope this helps

```
 <input
    type='text'
    id='title'
    value={state.title}
    onChange={event => {
      event.persist();
      setState(prevState => {
        return {
          ...prevState,
          title: event.target.value
        };
      });
    }}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you're reading the event data directly in the event handler, while the event is still *current*. In the second example however, you're reading it in the callback you pass to `setState()`. This callback gets invoked asynchronously when the state has been updated (that's the whole point of it) by which time the event handler has already returned and the native event (wrapped by React's SyntheticEvent) has been de-referenced. This is what you prevent by invoking `event.persist()`.